# Sending a http request in C# and catching network issues

Tags: c#, http

I previously had a small VBScript that would test if a specific website was accessible by sending a GET request. The script itself was extremely simple and did everything I needed:

```
Function GETRequest(URL) 'Sends a GET http request to a specific URL
   Dim objHttpRequest

   Set objHttpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
   objHttpRequest.Open "GET", URL, False

   On Error Resume Next 'Error checking in case access is denied
   objHttpRequest.Send

   GETRequest = objHttpRequest.Status
End Function
```

I now want to include this sort of functionality in an expanded C# application. However I've been unable to get the same results my previous script provided.

Using code similar to what I've posted below sort of gets me a proper result, but fails to run if my network connection has failed.

```
public static void GETRequest()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://url");
    request.Method = "GET";
    HttpStatusCode status;
    HttpWebResponse response;
    try
    {
       response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
       status = response.StatusCode;
       Console.WriteLine((int)response.StatusCode);
       Console.WriteLine(status);
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
       status = ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode;
       Console.WriteLine(status);
    }
}
```

But as I said, I need to know if the site is accessible, not matter the reason: the portal could be down, or the problem might reside on the side of the PC that's trying to access it. Either way: I don't care.

When I used `MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0` in the script I was able to get values ranging from **12000** to **12156** if I was having network problems. I would like to have the same functionality in my C# app, that way I could at least write a minimum of information to a log and let the computer act accordingly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A direct translation of your code would be something like this:

```
static void GetStatusCode(string url)
{
    dynamic httpRequest = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0"));
    httpRequest.Open("GET", url, false);

    try     { httpRequest.Send(); }
    catch   { }
    finally { Console.WriteLine(httpRequest.Status); }
}
```

It's as small and simple as your VBScript script, and uses the same COM object to send the request.

This code happily gives me error code like `12029 ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT` or `12007 ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` etc.

Comment: Thanks for providing me with such a direct translation of my script. It provides me with the correct response when my network connection is up, however, whenever I try to execute this piece of code when my network cable is unplugged the application hangs for about 10 seconds and then exits with no output...

Comment: Really? If I do the same, I get `12007 ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` after about 2 seconds.

Comment: I'm going to try this again on my PC at home. I'll let you know if I get a different response there.

Comment: I did a quick test with network disabled, and your VBScript and my C# code behave the same, as shown [here](http://imagebin.org/220348). Maybe the problem is something else?

Comment: Just checked your code on my desktop at home. It works precisely like you stated. I'm going to consult some colleagues at work tomorrow (who are more knowledgeable on network issues than me). Thanks again for providing the answer!

Comment: As a final comment: the code worked perfectly today. I don't know what went wrong yesterday, as I'm using the exact same code. Either way, all seems well now!

Answer (score 1):

If the code is failing only when you don't have an available network connection, you can use GetIsNetworkAvailable() before executing your code. This method will return a boolean indicating if a network connection is available or not. If it returns false, you could execute an early return / notify the user, and if not, continue.

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

using the code you provided above:

```
public static void GETRequest()
{
    if (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        return; //or alert the user there is no connection

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://url");
    request.Method = "GET";
    HttpStatusCode status;
    HttpWebResponse response;
    try
    {
       response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
       status = response.StatusCode;
       Console.WriteLine((int)response.StatusCode);
       Console.WriteLine(status);
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
       status = ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode;
       Console.WriteLine(status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, i've used it many times before, cut it down a bit for your needs: -

```
private static string GetStatusCode(string url)
{
      HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
      req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
      req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
      req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";

      try
      {
         HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

         foreach (string header in response.Headers)
         {
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", header, response.GetResponseHeader(header)));
         }

         return string.Format("Response Status Code: {0}\nServer:{1}\nProtocol: {2}\nRequest Method: {3}\n\n***Headers***\n\n{4}", response.StatusCode,response.Server, response.ProtocolVersion, response.Method, sb);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
          return string.Format("Error: {0}", e.ToString());
       }
}
```

Feel free to ignore the section that gets the headers

Comment: While this does indeed catch any exception that might occur, it still doesn't give me the error codes I received when using the **MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0** COM object.